# Gdb Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I want to use breakpoint in the UPtest function to stop at 0x000000000040124c.

[image]
[image]

run 111 222 333
[image]
[image]
I need to display the 32 records at the top of the stack.

x / 32wx $ esp, but show Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffe0a0.

I want to find the return address of the main program, how do I change it to display it?Like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: maybe you can just type `x/32wx 0x7fffffffffffe0a0`

Comment: If you're using an old textbook that refers to `$esp`, you can get close to what they're expecting by adding the `-m32` option to all the `gcc` commands.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're having is that the `$esp` register is 32-bit, but addresses on your target are 64-bit.  When you do `x/32wx $esp` GDB is reading the `$rsp` register, which has the value `0x7fffffffffffe0a0` and masking this to 32-bits, so `0xffffe0a0`, then it is sign extending this to 64-bit, giving `0xffffffffffffe0a0`.

Try `x/32wx $rsp` and you should have more luck.